# Hyperlink Text Clickable in Envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I currently have a Proposal template in Salesforce where I'm sending via Docusign through the SF to Docusign API.

Within the Salesforce Proposal, we have a Terms & Conditions statement that links out to the full T&C webpage.

The issue I'm finding is that when a recipient is reviewing the envelope, the T&C link is not clickable.  The link only works if they were to download/print the PDF file.

I've tried using custom anchor text tags but that does not seem to work either

Any ideas? Or anyone have a workaround to this?

I've tried using Custom Anchor tags from this documentation but cannot get it to auto-populate on the template or be a hyperlink - https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-to-create-a-hyperlink-in-DocuSign

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use responsive signing, such that the signer signs HTML and not PDF
You may need to use the demo env for now to test and work on this. 
Here is some documentation of this feature - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/responsive-signing/api-overview